# Unity HUB can't able to detect manually downloaded Unity Version

Tags: unity-game-engine

At present, within my Unity HUB, I have an older version of Unity 2019.2.10f1 so because of some problem, I want to use the latest downloadable version Unity 2019.2.21.

My Unity HUB current setup:
[image]

For this, I have downloaded the latest version from here:
[Unity download archive](https://unity3d.com/get-unity/download/archive)

After downloading become complete, I tried to add within the Unity HUB but I can't.
[image]

So how to add my manually Unity 2019.2.21 version within the Unity HUB?

Answer (score 0):

Inside the unity hub:
Click on
Intalls>Locate>(then browse the unity.exe file where you install)

It will automatically add

Comment: I think you have not checked my above screenshot which is from Unity HUB. "Select Editor" button remain disable when I locate my newly downloaded Unity.

Comment: have you selected that unity (file) shown in right pannel ?

Comment: Okay so this is not related to picking a folder but actually you have to select a Unity file - as I picked Unity file it worked. --- But then after there is no "Add Module" button within the Unity HUB so I can download other platforms for this Unity version.